# how to convert an orbeon form created by form builder to directly run in form runner?

Tags: orbeon

I have created a form in orbeon form builder, and now I want to pull the xforms code of it and run it directly form orbeon form runner? Is that possible? When I directly tried to copy and paste the source code of the form created by form builder, and put it in form runner it gives only a skeleton of tables etc.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I replied below but could you provide more details about why you would not use the Publish functionality? And how did you "put [the source code] in form runner"?

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a form created with Form Builder, use the Publish button. That will make it available to Form Runner by adding section templates and writing it to the database. This is the only way that will work properly.